# can't open an android emulator using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

i followed all the instructions in the tutorials, but from some reason i can't create the emulator....

what eclipsed showed me after trying to run:

```
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] ------------------------------
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] Android Launch!
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] Performing com.TheNewBoston.travis.StartingPoint activity launch
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'droidX'
[2013-09-06 12:24:30 - The New Boston] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'droidX'
[2013-09-06 12:24:33 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-09-06 12:24:33 - Emulator] 
[2013-09-06 12:24:33 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-09-06 12:24:33 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Do you have enough RAM? How much RAM have you given your virtual device?

Comment: What is your RAM size? It seems to be problem in memory.

Answer (score 1):

In IDE menu click on windows option. Go in android virtual device manager. If you created any emulator click on that emulator. then edit and in memory options. change RAM size to 256, 512 or 1024. Hope its work.